# Entity Framework model browser shows stored procedure twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For some (I guess valid ) reason the model browser shows the stored procedures twice. The `MyModel` node and `MyModel.Store` nodes BOTH have the stored procedure which I find a bit puzzling. Although editing the stored procedure details under one node seems to update the other as well. This isn't specific to one shown stored procedure, all stored procedures appear twice.

The MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738483%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't reveal much either. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyModel.Store` is the **physical** model - exactly what's contained in the database.

The `MyModel` is the **conceptual** model, which can be the same - but it could be different from the physical model, too.

That's why all things in EF are showing twice - the tables, views - everything. Once in a **physical** model, another time in the **conceptual** model - and then there's the mapping layer in between. That's the whole core structure of EF